# login prompt not displayed after boot

Tags: arch-linux, boot, login

On my Arch linux (x86-64) I use default login prompt (agetty + login), then after login X is automatically started by bash profile. After an update this weekend the login prompt from both agetty and login is not displayed.

I tried

1. putting `--noreset --noissue` to /etc/inittab:

   `c1:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty --noclear --noissue -8 -s 38400 tty1 linux`
2. putting `read` to /etc/rc.local

   actually I put `echo "Press enter"` before `read`, but it is not displayed as well
3. disabling all modules and daemons in `rc.conf`
4. disabling `vga=...` argument in `/boot/grub/menu.lst`

but nothing helped. Just after the `processing UDev events` messages are printed, something resets the screen and nothing is visible. Looking into `/etc/rc.sysinit` I found out that after udev, LOCALE is set and then `systemd-vconsole-setup` is called.

When I insert my login and password (nothing visible), X starts normally. Ctrl+Alt+F1 works after X is started, not before.

My graphic card is Intel X3100. I have `intel-dri`, `xf86-video-i740`, `xf86-video-intel` and `lib32-intel-dri` installed.

Comment: Is your `/usr` on a separate partition?

Comment: @jasonwryan no, only `/home` is separated

Comment: Boot from a live image and look at pacman's log and see what was in that last update...

Comment: @jasonwryan I can login into the system, I just don't see the login prompt and anything I type. When X starts, it is all ok. In the pacman log there is nothing wrong, just something about cabalized packages, but I don't use haskell anymore anyway.

Comment: Your part is not default inittab from Archlinux I think, is it? Download initscripts package and do 'xzcat initscripts-2012.06.1-1-any.pkg.tar.xz | tar -xvf - "etc/inittab' and replace. http://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/any/initscripts/

Comment: @JiriXichtkniha It is default inittab with `--noclear` and `--noissue` switches added. Nice nick btw

Comment: Have you tried to [add your module to your initramfs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel#KMS_.28Kernel_Mode_Setting.29)?

Comment: @jasonwryan This fixed the problem, although it is more like a workaround for `systemd-vconsole-setup` messing up my consoles. Can you please repost it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue seems to be related to [KMS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KMS). Try adding your video card module to your `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` MODULES line and rebuilding your intitramfs.

See the [Arch Wiki Intel page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel#KMS_.28Kernel_Mode_Setting.29) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with NVIDIA, setting nomodeset in kernel parameters fixed this problem in my case.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation).

Comment: @rahmu: Not really. The `nomodeset` parameter sometimes does resolve the issue that was mentioned in the question.